# SBT compilation fails if exception is thrown

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to `compile` [this Coursera assignment](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/programming/xIz9O/example-assignment) (after completing the aforementioned methods) from SBT shell in IntelliJ IDEA. As per the instructions, one of the methods is supposed to throw a `NoSuchElementException` if an empty list is passed to it.

However, when I do that, the compilation fails with the following output

```
[IJ]> compile
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/my-mac/courses/Scala/week_1/example/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.7. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 17.061 s
[error] /Users/my-mac/courses/Scala/week_1/example/src/main/scala/example/Lists.scala:52: object java.util.NoSuchElementException is not a value
[error]         throw NoSuchElementException
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed 26 Nov, 2017 7:55:30 PM
```

As a result, I'm unable to run the `test` command

On the other hand, if I return a value instead of throwing exception, the compilation succeeds while the test (obviously) fails

```
[IJ]> compile
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/my-mac/courses/Scala/week_1/example/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed 26 Nov, 2017 8:12:47 PM
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you forget a `new` operator?

Comment: Thanks @OlegPyzhcov, that was it. Being new to Scala, I'm still not sure as to when to use new and when to omit it. Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are doing a simple error:

You want to throw an instance of NoSuchElementException, meaning: `throw new NoSuchElementException()`

NoSuchElementException is a type, you can't throw types. I'm not seeing the full code, so I can't be sure, but it seems to be the problem